# Setup one docker container with ansible to provision another

Tags: docker, ansible, vagrant, provisioning

Is it possible to setup one docker image which installs ansible which then allows for the provisioning of a second docker container? I would've thought this was the way it was done for testing ansible scripts but am seeing a bunch of tutorials where it seems you need a second machine already available.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: Thanks Victor, do you mean two services in the docker-compose with the first one installing ansible? That's a good idea I'll give that a whirl.